# Getting child layout items to flex by percentage

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am using Angular Material layout directives and am having a problem getting child items to flex by certain percentages.

Consider the following

```
<md-card ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-margin layout-fill>
    <div flex-gt-sm="25">
      <label>Status</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
    <div flex>
      <label>Status</label>
      <div>Value</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-card>
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/parky128/pen/Bzoabw)

I would expect the first child to take up 25% of available space on screens above the `sm` breakpoint, and the second child to take up the rest (75%)

But this is not the case, I did find though, that if I remove `layout="column"` from the parent and so only have `layout-gt-sm="row"`then it works fine.

Why does it not work with both layout attributes defined?

Answer (score 0):

div defines the row for column and the column for row, where  will flex vertically for column and horizontally for row. Also it is a good idea if you want larger displays to show as row and smaller to show as column to define as row and use layout-wrap. In addition you have to consider how the parent (md-card) is handling the elements.

I try to stay away from layout-fill and use flex="auto" for safari support. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you have actually answered my question?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `layout-fill` attribute to `md-card` element since you want it to take whole available space. Here is the code.

```
<md-card ng-app="MyApp" style='background-color:pink' layout-fill>
 <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-margin layout-fill style="background-color:red">
  <div flex-gt-sm="25" style="background-color:blue">
   <label>Status</label>
   <div>Value</div>
  </div>
  <div flex style="background-color:yellow">
   <label>Status</label>
   <div>Value</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</md-card>
```

Here is the working Example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/WxQjzv

Comment: But that first child is not taking up 25% as per the `flex-gt-sm="25"` attribute